# how to update BIOS on Asus F5Z notebook?

Tags: bios

my current BIOS version is 208 I downloaded v210 from Asus website. Unzipped it, loaded AsusTek Bios ROM Easy Flash utility v1.12 but it cannot recognize the file. `Unable to recover the BIOS ROM contents.`

any idea?

Comment: Try the Asus forums...http://vip.asus.com/forum/default.aspx?SLanguage=en-us

Comment: well. I did my (re)search before posting this question. Didn't find any answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [WinFlash](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?model=WinFlash&f_name=WinFlashXP_32_z2303.zip&f_type=21&os=30) utility